# On responsive site, DIV covers slider but not on desktop

Tags: css, responsive-design

This site I've built at http://www.bridetobe.co.uk/ is doing something odd when I try and view it on a mobile device. I'm using some media queries to make it responsive and what happens when I view on a mobile #sitehead seems to be covering up most of #homepage_slider below(see image below).

[image: Responsive screenshot showing bug]

From looking at the CSS on #homepage_slider I don't see any absolute positioning making it be in a particular place in this instance.

Does anyone know how I can make #homepage_slider position itself below #sitehead rather than behind it?

Thanks

Comment: I can't see the image here. `position: fixed` for `#sitehead` causing the issue. Please remove it or change it to `position: relative` which will result in showing `#header-alias` at top of the page. Change it accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#sitehead` is position fixed  so you either need padding at the top of the body (matching the height of your header) to push you slider down or not have your header fixed (make it relative).  It works on the desktop as your sitehead is relative.